# Remove indentation is not working on my instance of Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

Since I am coding in `python` indentation is particularly essential.

Normally, I can indent and unindent blocks of code using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>, respectively. However, on my new cloud installation only indent works, while <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> does nothing.

In the `Keyboard Shortcuts` menu I do not see any setting for unindent. Is there something I need to do to make unindent work?

Comment: Tab and Shift-Tab can serve as a workaround.

Comment: <kbd>Tab</kbd> just moves the cursor around to other panes, e.g. to the TERMINAL window.

Comment: What's the shortcut of `markdown.extension.onIndentLines`?  Have you tried to click the `Record Keys` button to search `Ctrl+[`? And maybe some application occupies this shortcut.